# .Net free open-source components to generate PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

The task is to generate 2-3 pages PDF file, which may contain tables, with borders and without, nested tables, and simple formatting (align, text size, bold/italic). Input may be anything from markdown, or html, but some strict format to create a template. Output - pdf. Everything should be server side.

I have already researched in many libraries. iText is not supporting tables, others are expensive or require Word/IE to generate a file...

Is there any free libraries, which support this for C#?

Comment: iText does support this, it just requires some work.  [Check out this tutorial](http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/how-to-create-table-in-pdf-document-using-Asp-Net-with-C-Sharp-and-itextsharp-1027.aspx).  In terms of a template, you can create a class to manage your templates/tables.  BTW I found this by simply typing "generate PDF table c#" in google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iTextSharp does support tables (PdfPTable).

- Versions 4.1.6 and below are LGPL/MPL licence, and are free of charge
- Versions 5+ are not free.

I used to use iTextSharp around version 4 and I'm sure all of your requirements are met. Try it out!

Comment: *Versions 5+ are not free.* - Correction: Versions 5+ are double licensed, AGPL or commercial, and are free of charge as long as your program (in a broad sense) is licensed using a licence compatible with AGPL

Comment: Fantastic. thank you! Unfortunately, I was not digging so deep.

Answer (score 2):

ABC Pdf works very well, but its around $250 :( they offer a free trial though.

Few other alternatives will be. iTextSharp is really good :)

iTextSharp 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

PDF Sharp.
http://sharppdf.sourceforge.net/

PDF Clown
http://www.stefanochizzolini.it/en/projects/clown/index.html